# Find the text to a New York law: DASA

Tags: new-york-state, education

I am looking for the text to the Dignity for All Students Act (New York).  There have been a couple of amendments and if I can read those too, so much the better.

I have looked at half a dozen sites that have dead links to the law itself.  Frustrating!

Here's the closest I've gotten:

I found a [site](http://www.bullypolice.org/ny_law.html) that seems to have the full text to the law, but it's not an official site.  Would prefer something connected with government.

I found a [site](http://www.queeringeducation.org/policy/dasa) that shows some of the highlights of the law.

Comment: What does the DASA law practically require for teachers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original 2010 bill is [A03661](http://assembly.state.ny.us/leg/?default_fld=&leg_video=&bn=A03661&term=2009&Summary=Y&Text=Y) and the [2012 enacted bill A10712](http://assembly.state.ny.us/leg/?default_fld=&leg_video=&bn=A10712&term=2011&Actions=Y&Text=Y) amended it. It is probably most useful to read the bills in order, if you're interested in the unified picture or what the changes were. The effect on the revised code is the legal "bottom line", and you can start [here](http://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2015/edn/title-1/article-2/) to find the current state of the law.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!  Regarding your last link (the current state of the law), is there a way to view or download the whole thing?  At the link you provided, one can only view one section at a time.  If that's not possible, that's okay.

Comment: Apparently, the last published consolidation of the laws was over 100 years ago. Really annoying, I must say.

Comment: I don't get it.  This law isn't that old, and the internet wasn't around either 100 years ago.

Comment: Yes, and that's basically why there isn't a single consolidation of the laws. You can get the piece by piece version, or the individual bills passed by the assembly with the additions and deletions.

Comment: Is that a New York thing?

Comment: It's actually a general thing in the US that online versions are never complete, and at least are listed in a title-by-title fashion. Washington has about 100 "titles"; it turns out they archive the revision every year. New York apparently has not have an official "update" since 1910.